# Sorting MongoDB documents with the same update-timestamps?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to test a route in my `Express` server with `Supertest`. On that route i will get a list of data from the `MongoDB` and that data is **sorted by the updatedAt field**.

I wan to test if the order in the output is the right way, but I have a problem - it seems that mongoDb is so fast that some of the documents have the same timestamp (didn't think that was possible).

[image]

How is this sorted internally? It seems like it is not sorted by _id either. Here is the function in my test that generates the documents:

```
let first;
let last;
Array.from(Array(14)).forEach((e, i) => {
  const immo = new Immo({ user: this.user.model });
  immo.save();
  if (i === 2) {
    // last means last with limit 12 sorted by timestamps descending
    last = immo._id.toString();
  }
  if (i === 13) {
    // the last that was put in will be the first in the sorted list
    first = immo._id.toString();
  }
});
```

The output is the last 12 items that the user has edited. I save the first and the last so I can assert them later in the test.

But the test fails because there are 3 or 4 with the same timestamp and the one that is actually the last in order of how I put it in the DB is not really the last when Mongo sorts it by timestamps (or first in descending order).

I tried to make a delay via for-loop in the input-loop but that did nothing. (Should I maybe not use Array.forEach?)

**Is there any way I can make sure that there is at least a few MS delay between the documents?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was that I didn't consider the asynchronous nature of all the processes.

I wrapped everything in Promises and it works now. Here is my new code:

```
it('should return a list of the last 12 objects if a user has 14 objects', function (done) {
    let first;
    let last;
    let i = 0;
    const model = this.user.model;
    (function recur() {
      i += 1;
      return new Immo({ user: model })
        .save()
        .then((result) => {
          if (i === 3) {
            last = result._id.toString();
          } else if (i === 14) {
            first = result._id.toString();
          }
          if (i >= 14) {
            return result;
          }
          return recur();
        });
    }())
    .then(() => {
      this.request(this.app)
        .get(url)
        .set('Authorization', this.authHeader)
        .expect(200)
        .end((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            done.fail(err.message);
          } else {
            expect(res.body.count).toBe(14);
            expect(res.body.objects.length).toBe(12);
            expect(res.body.objects[0]._id).toEqual(first);
            expect(res.body.objects[11]._id).toEqual(last);
            done();
          }
        });
    });
```

Not sure if this would work below `ES2015` since I use the generating function recursively.

Mongoose complains when I use it's own Promises. Then I do this on top of my test-setup function:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;
```

I hope it was worth it to waste so much time on this one test :D